# EXCEL-VBA-How To Swap Cell Protection of Two Ranges

Tags: excel, vba

The following code below swaps the values of two ranges:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim StoredRng As Variant

Set rng = Selection

'Store first selected cell area
  StoredRng = rng.Areas(1).Cells.Value

'Swap first area with the second
rng.Areas(1).Cells.Value = rng.Areas(2).Cells.Value
    For Each cell In rng.Areas(1)
        If rng.Areas(1).Locked = False Then
            rng.Locked = True
        End If
        
    Next
        
  
'Populate second area with the first
rng.Areas(2).Cells.Value = StoredRng
    For Each cell In rng.Areas(2)
        If rng.Areas(2).Locked = False Then
            rng.Locked = True
        End If
    Next
```

However, I want to swap the protection as well.  In other words, if area1 has all locked cells except for two cells and area2 has all locked cells, how can I swap protection of them?

Comment: Are all the cells in an area the same protection?  As in all the cells in range 1 are locked, there are no mixing.

Comment: No sir.  Area1 is all locked except for two cells. Area2 is all locked.  I updated my question.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Then you will need loop one of the areas and do the same as you are with the formula to the locked/unlocked.  Or if you do not care you can do a copy paste special of the formats.

Comment: I want the formats to remain unchanged.  Just swap the values and cell protection only.

Comment: I'm guessing too that you should probably verify that both areas are the same size.

Comment: Then you will need to loop and do each cell individually.

Comment: @BigBen Yes sir.  Both ranges are the same size

Comment: Yes but your code should verify that, not assume it. Just as your code assumes that `rng` has at least 2 areas. Also if you're concerned with the value of two ranges, then clearer to use `.Value` and not `.Formula`.

Comment: @BigBen Ah great catch.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @ScottCraner See my answer attempt.  This is not working.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ScottCraner I modified my question instead and deleted my answer

Comment: @ScottCraner I couldn't get it to work with looping but I found another way

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test_swapLocked()

With ThisWorkbook
    'This fails due to unequal ranges
    Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = Union(.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), .Names("rg.1.1").RefersToRange, .Names("rg.1.2").RefersToRange)
   'This succeeds
   'Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = Union(.Names("rg.1.1").RefersToRange, .Names("rg.1.2").RefersToRange)
    Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = Union(.Names("rg.2.1").RefersToRange, .Names("rg.2.2").RefersToRange)
End With

Dim isLocked1 As Boolean, islocked2 As Boolean
isLocked1 = rg1.Areas(2).Cells(1, 2).Locked
islocked2 = rg2.Areas(2).Cells(1, 2).Locked

Debug.Assert isLocked1 <> islocked2

swapLockedForTwoRanges rg1, rg2

Debug.Assert rg1.Areas(2).Cells(1, 2).Locked = islocked2
Debug.Assert rg2.Areas(2).Cells(1, 2).Locked = isLocked1

End Sub



Public Sub swapLockedForTwoRanges(rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range)

If areRangesOfSameSize(rg1, rg2) = False Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError, , "Ranges have to be of same size"
End If

Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range

Dim isLocked1 As Boolean, islocked2 As Boolean

Dim a As Long, r As Long, c As Long

For a = 1 To rg1.Areas.Count
    For r = 1 To rg1.Areas(a).Rows.Count
        For c = 1 To rg1.Areas(a).Columns.Count
            Set c1 = rg1.Areas(a).Cells(r, c): Set c2 = rg2.Areas(a).Cells(r, c)
            isLocked1 = c1.Locked: islocked2 = c2.Locked
            c1.Locked = islocked2: c2.Locked = isLocked1
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub



Public Function areRangesOfSameSize(rg1 As Range, rg2 As Range) As Boolean

Dim a As Long, r As Long, c As Long

If rg1.Areas.Count <> rg2.Areas.Count Then Exit Function

For a = 1 To rg1.Areas.Count
    For r = 1 To rg1.Areas(a).Rows.Count
        If rg1.Areas(a).Rows.Count <> rg2.Areas(a).Rows.Count Then Exit Function
        For c = 1 To rg1.Areas(a).Columns.Count
            If rg1.Areas(a).Rows(r).Columns.Count <> rg2.Areas(a).Rows(r).Columns.Count Then Exit Function
        Next
    Next
Next
areRangesOfSameSize = True

End Function
```

Comment: Please add a description explaining the changes you made to the code to make a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer myself.  The code below has been tested and works:

```
Set rng1 = Range("Q47:Q48")
Set rng2 = Range("S47:S48")

Range(rng1, rng2).Select

If rng1.Locked = False Then
    rng1.Locked = True
    rng2.Locked = False
    
ElseIf rng2.Locked = False Then
    rng1.Locked = False
    rng2.Locked = True
End If
```